# How can I find users coming from Google, based on $SERVER array data?

Tags: php, server

I have wrote a small PHP code on my host to keep IP, agent, URL, ... data of all accesses.
I register most of $SERVER array arguments.
How can I find users coming from Google (search or advertise), based on $SERVER array data?

Comment: Does [HTTP_REFERER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) work for you? Check if HTTP_REFERER is www.google.com or google.com. Just note this header can be "spoofed".

Comment: Put certain GET arguments in your link that you advertise with. That would give you who came from an Ad and the rest of the website hits would be from other means. Your link could be something like www.mysite/index.php?location=myad

Comment: Thank you, good hints.

Actually, my mistake was this: "There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these", which was mentioned in php.net.

I used to use `print_r($_SERVER)` to find indices, but most of time, **HTTP_REFERER** was not included.

Answer (score 1):

I used **HTTP_REFERER** argument of `$_SERVER`.
Because Google ad landing page is different with site main pages, I can now make separation between different users, regarding to this steps:

1. **HTTP_REFERER** shows the referrer; if it is google.xxx, then I make sure that the user has come from Google,
2. if the **REQUEST_URI** equals the landing page, I make sure that the user has come from google ad,
3. if the **REQUEST_URI** is not same as landing page, it means the user has come from google search results.

Thanks to x43 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/14511890/x43) for his good hint.